# How to write multiple image files iteratively to documents folder in swift swiftui ios

Tags: ios, swift, document, nsfilemanager

```
@ObservedObject foldersData = FoldersViewModel()    

func genThumbnails() -> Void {
        for ind in subDirNames.indices{
            for indd in galContents[ind].indices{
                if foldersData.subDirNames[ind] == "Root Folder"{
                    foldersData.genThumbnailFiles(FoldersViewModel.resizedImage(at: foldersData.galContents[ind][indd], for: CGSize(width: FoldersViewModel.imageSize[0]/4, height: FoldersViewModel.imageSize[1]/4))!, filename: (foldersData.galContents[ind][indd] as NSString).lastPathComponent, directoryPath: NSHomeDirectory().appending("/Documents/Thumbnails/"))}
                else{
                    foldersData.genThumbnailFiles(FoldersViewModel.resizedImage(at: foldersData.galContents[ind][indd], for: CGSize(width: FoldersViewModel.imageSize[0]/4, height: FoldersViewModel.imageSize[1]/4)) ?? UIImage(), filename: (foldersData.galContents[ind][indd] as NSString).lastPathComponent, directoryPath: NSHomeDirectory().appending("/Documents/Thumbnails/" + foldersData.subDirNames[ind]))
                }
                counts[0] = counts[0] + 1
            }
            counts[1] = counts[1] + 1
        }
        //isLoading.toggle()
        foldersData.isLoading = false
    }

func genThumbnailFiles(_ chosenImage: UIImage, filename: String, directoryPath: String) -> String {
    //let directoryPath =  NSHomeDirectory().appending("/Documents/Thumbnails/")
    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: directoryPath) {
        do {
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: NSURL.fileURL(withPath: directoryPath), withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMddhhmmss"

    //let filename = dateFormatter.string(from: Date()).appending(".jpg")
    //let filepath = directoryPath.appending(filename)
    let filepath = directoryPath+"/\(filename)"
    let url = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: filepath)
    print(directoryPath.appending(filename))
    do {
        try chosenImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)?.write(to: url, options: .atomic)
        return String.init(directoryPath+"/\(filename)")
    } catch {
        print(error)
        print("file cant not be save at path \(filepath), with error : \(error)");
        return filepath
    }
}
```

So I am trying to develop an app for ios that will allow me to view my old photos from my old devices (I used to own multiple type of devices such as android, windows phone etc),

So, in order to handle thumbnails, I wanted to handle them in the beginning by resizing them and adding them to apps documents directory, this way I wont need to resize every-time when thumbnail is loaded,

However when I try that, error pops up during arbitrary file writing procedure, saying memory could not be allocated:

> /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A5FD35C8-B41D-43BC-A809-4C2BEA92DDEA/Documents/US - Pixel 2 2019-08-31/IMG_20181003_145023.jpg
> 2021-08-27 03:54:43.687807-0400 myapp[5612:701316] [myapp] _CFDataCreateWithMappedFile:181: could not mmap '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A5FD35C8-B41D-43BC-A809-4C2BEA92DDEA/Documents/US - Pixel 2 2019-08-31/IMG_20181003_145023.jpg':  error: 12 (Cannot allocate memory)
> myapp(5612,0x10059b880) malloc: can't allocate region

I also see memory (RAM) usage gradually increases (from say 25mb to 250mb) during my jpg write process,

Anything would be helpful, I tried to use third party libraries such as Nuke to load thumbnails during scrolling however, that process is power hungry and was meant to be used to load smaller amount of files from the online server I assume,

I have like thousands of photos that I would like to be able to browse like I am in photos app, unfortunately apple makes it hard to load external files to its own photos app and organize them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects in iOS are guaranteed to be released only after leaving the scope of `autoreleasepool`. There is a default pool that runs every time the frame is updated.

If you allocate and release memory many times during one cycle, you can add your own `autoreleasepool` to ensure that this memory is released immediately:

```
func genThumbnails() -> Void {
    for ind in subDirNames.indices{
        for indd in galContents[ind].indices{
            autoreleasepool {
                if foldersData.subDirNames[ind] == "Root Folder"{
                    foldersData.genThumbnailFiles(FoldersViewModel.resizedImage(at: foldersData.galContents[ind][indd], for: CGSize(width: FoldersViewModel.imageSize[0]/4, height: FoldersViewModel.imageSize[1]/4))!, filename: (foldersData.galContents[ind][indd] as NSString).lastPathComponent, directoryPath: NSHomeDirectory().appending("/Documents/Thumbnails/"))}
                else{
                    foldersData.genThumbnailFiles(FoldersViewModel.resizedImage(at: foldersData.galContents[ind][indd], for: CGSize(width: FoldersViewModel.imageSize[0]/4, height: FoldersViewModel.imageSize[1]/4)) ?? UIImage(), filename: (foldersData.galContents[ind][indd] as NSString).lastPathComponent, directoryPath: NSHomeDirectory().appending("/Documents/Thumbnails/" + foldersData.subDirNames[ind]))
                }
            }
            counts[0] = counts[0] + 1
        }
        counts[1] = counts[1] + 1
    }
    //isLoading.toggle()
    foldersData.isLoading = false
}
```

Comment: Wow. Very simple solution and it indeed exactly what solved my issue. Thanks a lot!